# I can not run nodejs javascript file in MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, batch-file

**I have a software to get attached file from specific email real time.
It had made by node js.
It works well window 7.
Here is Directory structure.**

- > --- `myfolder`

> ```
> |
> -- node_modules (<code>imap</code>,<code>mime</code>,<code>fs</code>,<code>ftp</code> ......) 
> -- run.bat
> -- uploadCSV.js</li>
> ```
>
> For `MacOS`, I have made run.command file instead of run.bat file.

```
Content of run.bat  ---  node upload.CSV

Content of run.command --- #!/bin/bash

                       node uploadCSV.js
```

**When I installed `nodejs` in `MacOS` and double click run.command, some error comes up like below.**

---

```
Last login: Fri Jan 16 10:19:23 on ttys000
Mimis-Mac-mini:~ mimi$ /Users/mimi/Documents/app/run.command ; exit;
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
'rror: Cannot find module '/Users/mimi/uploadCSV.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929(cat)
logout
```

---

**I don't know well about shell script for MacOS.
Help me ! Why can I fix this error?
Thanks, Tomi**

Comment: Your "require" statement seems to be looking for an "absolute" path. It needs to be relative to the application install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your current working directory. You're executing "node uploadCSV.js" from your user's home directory. Node is trying to load uploadCSV.js from /Users/mimi. This is why you get the error "Cannot find module /Users/mimi/uploadCSV.js".

You can fix it by simply cd-ing (change directory) into the folder with the node file.

```
$ cd /Users/mimi/Documents/app/
$ ./run.command
```

You could also change run.command to contain the full path of the node script:

```
node /Users/mimi/Documents/app/uploadCSV.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
"Cannot find module" error has been fixed.

Comment: By the way I have found new errors.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984954/when-connect-to-gmail-using-nodejs-imap-in-macos-some-error-comes-up
can you help me? 
Thanks.