# When connect to gmail using nodejs imap in MacOS, some error comes up

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, gmail, imap

I have a `node.js` program to watch specific email from my supplier.
It works well on a windows 7 system, but it does not work in MacOS.

When run shell script in MacOS terminal, some error comes up.
This is the shell command I run:

```
#!/bin/bash
node uploadCSV.js
```

(This command is in run.command file)

This is the whole error I  had seen:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Invalid credentials v46mb316321295eeg
.............
```

And first part to connect to my gmail in js file that I had run:

> var Imap = require('imap'),
>       inspect = require('util').inspect;
>
> var imap = new Imap({   user: 'tomitanaka999@gmail.com',   password:
>   'greatlife',   host: 'imap.gmail.com',   port: 993,   tls: true });
>
> var fs = require('fs'); var base64  = require('base64-stream'); var
>   Client = require('ftp'); var fs = require('fs');

Who can help me?
I'd like to fix this error as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm going to assume that these aren't your real credentials...

Comment: I've used correct credentials and it work correctly in windows7.
But it does not work in MacOS.
Thanks,

Comment: I think @reto 's point was that you should not post real credentials in public web site...